# How to reuse a dynamic form in smartGWT?

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am currently using two exactly similar dynamic forms on two tabs. But now to improve performance i want to reuse the same form in two tabs. Is there any way to reuse a dynamic form? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that. http://forums.smartclient.com/showpost.php?p=4060&postcount=2
There is a workaround. Make your tabs empty and catch tabset events to determine the active tab. Put your tabs content as memmbers of layout and show only active member.
Take into account than show/hide operatoins are much faster than add/delete.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Singaltone Pattern. Please look at [this](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-singleton-design-pattern) link. It allows the user to use same object without creating again & again.

Comment: No. This is not the soliution. If a smart GWT component is reused in the form, then only one gets displayed and not the other one. Is there any other way to do this?